# With a Private Queue NSManagedObjectContext, do I need to access properties of NSManagedObjects on the private queue?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, ui-thread

I'm finally getting to my To-Do list item to update old app code to use a Private Queue for my NSManagedObjectContext, but I'm running into some awkward situations and I can't find what I consider a clear answer.

If I'm accessing simple properties on an NSManagedObject, do I need to do that on the Private Queue as well?

It's causing me problems with table views and such. For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    cell.textLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Is that ok to do when my context is in a private queue and I'm accessing the object value from the main ui thread?

The above is a very simple example, just to explain my point, but I've got more complicated examples throughout my code. Like when dealing with building swipe actions, I feel like I'm bouncing back and forth between ui-private-ui-private-ui in order to just handle a tap on a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed objects can only be used on the queue where they were fetched, so if you fetch on a private queue, you can only use the object on that queue. That includes accessing the properties of the object. There are a few exceptions to this rule-- you can look up the managed object ID, for example, and do a few other basic things (see [the class docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject) for a full list), but that doesn't directly help here.

Depending on the details of your app, one or more of the following might help:

- Use `performBlockAndWait:` to retrieve the property values. This might block the UI if the private queue is busy with something else though.
- Change the fetch request to get dictionaries as the fetch result instead of managed objects, by setting `resultType` on the fetch request to `NSDictionaryResultType`. This is fine if you're only reading the data, but it may be awkward to save changes since you don't have a managed object to work on.
- Get the object's ID and then use `objectWithId:` to look up the same object on a different context that uses the main queue. Or if you have a bunch of objects, you can do a new fetch for all of the object IDs, again on the main queue.
- Fetch from a main-queue context.

Comment: Blerg. This means that using a context with a Private queue is essentially such a ridiculous amount of work that I'll essentially never do it. :/ Since iOS 14, we've been getting all sorts of Firebase reports of crashes in crazy places deep inside Core Data and I thought that maybe switching over and putting all of our code in performBlock or performBlockAndWait would solve the problem, but doing it on a private queue seems completely ludicrous. :(

Comment: Private queues are really not intended for UI work. Trying to use them that way is not good app design.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely got that from your explanation, I'm just trying to understand what the point of the Private Queue context is then. Is really just for temporarily running a data task in the background and that's it?

Comment: They're useful for importing data, for example from web services. Download and import on a private queue, then read on the main queue. They're also good for fetches that may take a long time, such as when using complex predicates. Fetch on a private queue, then pass the resulting object IDs back to the main queue and look them up there.